# How to find out the following integral which is used in solution of wave equation?

Tags: definite-integrals, wave-equation

I have to find out the value of following integral $$\int_0^t\int_{x-t+s}^{x+t-s} f(y,s) \ dy \ ds$$ where $f(t,x)$ =  \begin{cases} 
      1 \quad if  & -1\leq x\leq 1, \ 0\leq t \leq 1 \\
      0 \ \qquad \text{otherwise}
   \end{cases}
I am completely confused how to do this?